# How do I change from as_slice() to [] syntax?

Tags: syntax, rust, slice

Recompiling some older code against the newer nightlies, I'm getting warnings on using the `as_slice()` syntax in favour of the `var[]` syntax.

However when I replace `as_slice()` with `[]` as shown [in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0198-slice-notation.md), I get a compiler error saying:

```
 expected `&str`,
    found `str`
(expected &-ptr,
    found str) [E0308]
src/main.rs:38         print_usage(program[], opts);
```

compared to my original

```
print_usage(program.as_slice(), opts);
```

Is the `as_slice()` syntax going away entirely, or is it just more idiomatic to write it as `vec[]`? What's the deal with the error I'm getting when I follow what the compiler is asking me to do?

Comment: For reference, the new syntax is referred to as [Index](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html), which is the trait that allows it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were near to success:

```
print_usage(&program[], opts);
```

So yes, now we should use square brackets syntax as `&[start .. end]` or `&mut [start .. end]` instead of `as_slice`/`slice`/`slice_from`/`slice_to`.

Comment: I think that due to the new deref coercion rules even just `&program` (without brackets) will suffice (if `program` is a `String` or something else with `Deref<Target=str>`).